# Is there a resource that describes the fauna of the Forgotten Realms more specifically?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, forgotten-realms

This is in relation to [my other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109171/are-pcs-able-to-appraise-the-difficulty-of-an-encounter).

Is there a resource available that describes where the creatures of D&D are found more specifically? How common or rare they might be in that area or other areas? How common the knowledge of said creature might be?

My players are all very inexperienced, and my memory is slowly getting worse. I can't recall everything I read in multiple monster books. Even then the books don't usually make any mention of their locale, rarity, or common knowledge.

Does the average villager know about Perytons? Would a traveler or an adventurer? What Intelligence (Nature) DC do I use to determine whether my players know (and *what* they know) about Harpies (or any other creature)?

I'm looking for something pretty concrete here and not just DM's choice, because I don't know how to go about it myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The *Monsters of Faerun* book gives these details.**

[image: Monsters of Faerun]

*(This book is for D&D 3.5, but the campaign setting information is still relevant.)*

The book includes not only mechanics and statistics about the creatures, but also setting information about how they fit into the world.  According to [this article](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20010216a) (emphasis mine):

> Each monster entry includes a few paragraphs under the heading, "In
>   the Realms." These sections **give specific details of the monsters as
>   they relate to Faerûn,** the world of the Forgotten Realms

However, keep in mind that the monsters are intended to appear wherever the DM feels is appropriate.  The article also confirms that the DM should not feel creatively limited by location and lore, and should insert these monsters in whatever adventures they wish.

> The monsters found in Monster Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn could
>   appear in any Dungeons & Dragons campaign . . . and probably will.

Comment: I think I used to own that book hahah! Location is probably the least important part of my question. Knowledge of the creatures existence and general info about them is more important. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

As far as concrete answers, I don't think there's anything like that in 5th edition as yet.

Since most of the monsters in D&D are pretty ridiculously fatal to commoners or city guards, I'd expect them to be the subjects of rumor and speculation more than direct knowledge, outside of the occasional ex-adventurer or scholar who actually focuses on knowing about such things.  Even things that do live in the area around a town would probably be more story than fact.

Some of the more peaceful creatures might be less mysterious, but I would expect your average townsperson's knowledge of Perytons to be limited to vague stories about where they come from and what they do, and knowledge of which sounds to run away from really fast.