# Is 6 groups of fairly established individuals too much for early game?

Tags: campaign-development, balance

I'm acting as the GM for a grimdark game called Pandemonio that a friend of mine discovered.  I'm relatively new to being a GM and definitely new to being a GM of grimdark.

We've not yet had our first session and I have planned for a potential of 6 groups that can come to hate my players, potentially just in the first 3 sessions alone.  Of these, only half of the groups that they could actually defeat entirely, and even then it is unlikely that they will until later in the game.  The other groups are well-established group with a large force at their backs, think FBI on steroids.

Basically, I like the concepts I've come up with, and 3 of the groups that would go after my players will only do so if certain conditions are met, as a form of punishment almost for being too noisy in a game that is supposed to be about concealing a secret war and saving what people they can.

However, I worry that I may be going too far in just the pre-planning stage, and want my players to actually be able to enjoy the game to its full extent without putting in so many enemies that they aren't even given a chance.

What level of threat is appropriate for players new to Pandemonio?

Comment: I added a question at the end that I hope summarized your conern.  OBTW, Welcome! :-) Please take the [tour] to get the most out of the RPG.SE site.  If that question isn't quite what you were asking, please edit your question, and that question, to more clearly state what question you have about starting your players in this game.

Comment: I have asked a somewhat similar [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/what-to-do-when-a-player-character-does-something-that-seems-suicidal).